# iterate all documents->_ids in mongodb, php

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm currently doing this:

```
  $t_category = 781;
  $res = $collection->findOne(array("_id" => intval($t_category)));
```

this way i am getting only one category (it was just to try). How can I get all categories (documents->_ids) in php->mongo? A way I could iterate over all the documents in the collection. I have tried the find with no arguments. No luck. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `find` with no arguments will return all items in the collection.

```
$results = $collection->find();
```